# How to append % symbol in input type=text on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a number spinner, and I want the input to have % symbol in the text box, by default. I tried using span, but it adds the symbol outside the box.

Comment: It works fine. The % symbol is displayed inside the text box. What is your issue?

Comment: No, when I use the up and down keys, it appends percent symbol, but when I manually add some number in the input box, it only shows the number and not the percent symbol.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery change event. It will add '%' symbol at the end of your input.

```js
(function($) {
  var minNumber = -100;
  var maxNumber = 100;
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.spinner input').val() == maxNumber) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.spinner input').val(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 5 + '%');
    }
  });

  $('.txtinput').on("change", function() {
    var inputVal = parseFloat($(this).val().replace('%', '')) || 0

    if (minNumber > inputVal) {
      inputVal = -100;
    } else if (maxNumber < inputVal) {
      inputVal = 100;
    }

    $(this).val(inputVal + '%');
  });

  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.spinner input').val() == minNumber) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.spinner input').val(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 5 + '%');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=spinner class="container">
  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control txtinput" value="0">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="color: #C41C01"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color: #20AD4E"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It keeps adding multiple `%` symbols, if you keep typing in numbers.

Comment: This is not working properly. It is adding percent symbol on every key entry!

Comment: @ Mohit Bhardwaj @PriyankaPachori I changed event from keyup to change, please check.

Comment: This code lets me enter value more than 100, and less than -100, while I have already defined maximum and minimum values to be 100 and -100 respectively.

Comment: @PriyankaPachori I updated the code, so if you enter more than 100 it will set to 100 and if it is less than -100 it will set to -100 (But using buttons i can change it more than 100 or less than -100. is it intentional ?)

Comment: No, using buttons also it should allow within the same range. The previous code was taking care of that validation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple css trick for that, just add this to your code:

```
.spinner input {
  padding-right: 13px;
}

.spinner .input-group-btn-vertical::before {
  content: "%";
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

It uses **::before** pseudo element selector to add the **%** sign to the textbox. Here is working example:

```js
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 100px;
}
.spinner input {
  text-align: right;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn:last-child {
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
}

.spinner input {
  padding-right: 13px;
}

.spinner .input-group-btn-vertical::before {
  content: "%";
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header"><h1>Bootstrap 3 input-spinner</h1></div>  
  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

(Also in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4c7pxLq/))

Comment: Thanks, yes, it should be **::before**, I've just edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```js
(function ($) {
     var minNumber = -100;
     var maxNumber = 100;
     $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
         if($('.spinner input').val() == maxNumber){
             return false;
         }else{
             $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 5 +'%');
         }
     });

     $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
         if($('.spinner input').val() == minNumber){
             return false;
         }else{
             $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) -5+'%');
         }
     });
  
  $(".spinner input").on("input", function(){
    var intValue = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/%/g, '') ) || 0;
    
    $(this).val( intValue + '%' );
  });
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=spinner class="container">
  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="color: #C41C01">Up</i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color: #20AD4E">Down</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i enter any words inside the textbox, It showing NaN% and even textbox is not responding.

Comment: @ArunCM Please check updated code. If you enter invalid number e.g. `abc`, it shows `0%`( earlier it shows them as `NaN%` ). The textbox does not stop responding. It works with both Up and Down buttons and you can type in value or delete values by selecting them with mouse or `shift+arrow`. `Backspace` is not effective because every time you hit backspace, it removes the `%` symbol, and the code logic appends `%` symbol again at the end. So, it seems it is not responding.

Comment: I am not able to delete and reenter. Backspace is not working perhaps.

Comment: @PriyankaPachori Yes, backspace does not work. You can select multiple characters using mouse or pressing back arrow key with shift key held down. If then you hit backspace, it will seem to work. Moreover, you can add a condition for backspace key only.