# Javascript - How to add percentage symbol at the end [no jquery]

Tags: javascript

I need to add a `'%'` symbol to the values entered into an input field. How can I do this using javascript only (**not using jquery or other libs**).

Example:

When I type "34" in the input field it should appear as "34%". Below is my input field sample:

```
<input type="text"  id="amountId" onkeydown="change(event)" />
```

Comment: do you wish the value to remain as 34 from the perspective of the form, or to be 34%? did you check the CSS only answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38520939/4007992

Answer (score 4):

With a text field, that's relatively easy:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('amountId');

input.addEventListener('blur', function () { // as soon as the input element loses focus, "%" is appended
  input.value += '%';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amountId" />
```

However, there are a few things to note:

- It's not very user-friendly (if the user wants to change the value from 34 to 35, he or she has to delete the `%` character).
- If the user inputs non-numeric values (`foobar`), `%` also is appended.

For these reasons, I would just use a `<input type="number">`:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100">%
```

Comment: unfortunately the 1st solution the '%' appears multiple times. the 2nd second solution have the % solution outside and type number shows an up down arrow in chrome at time.  i only wanted input text type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution by extensive use of `event.preventDefault()`  to prevent non-numberic character from printing and re-rendering the value in each key down.The number part of the value is parsed first and I append the pressed key value and % symbol at the end of the string. Sorry I can't share the full solution because it's logic is customized further for my specific usecase.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('#amountId').blur(function(e){
        var thisVal = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        $('#amountId').val(thisVal + '%');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="amountId" onkeydown="change(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading in the future: If you want to do what PeterMader suggested without adding a new "%" everytime you edit the inputfield, just do

```
var input = document.getElementById('amountId');

input.addEventListener('blur', function () { 
  input.value += '%';
});

input.addEventListener('keydown', function () { 
  rente.value = rente.value.replace('%', '')  //This simply removes the "%" when you start typing again
});
```