# How to add % in input tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const initiatlState = { weight: "" };
const [data, setData] = useState(initiatlState);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  };

<input type="text" name="weight" value={data.weight +"%"} 
onChange={handleChange} placeholder="weight" />
```

I want to show when I type 50 value will be 50 % but I am getting %5%0 like this.

Comment: What is the actual data-type of `weight`?

Comment: Here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520503/how-to-append-symbol-in-input-type-text-on-user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520503/how-to-append-symbol-in-input-type-text-on-user-input)

Comment: Note that HTML text inputs do not support "masks" or formatting their user-entered values _as they're typed in_ (at least not without enraging the user). Are you wanting to re-format the contents of the input after the input loses focus instead?

Comment: @ДөлгөөнМөнхчулуун That answer doesn't work in this case because that answer uses jQuery to edit the DOM directly, but with React/Redux you must not touch the DOM directly (and also because jQuery is dead now).

Comment: after the input loses focus instead, Yeah that will work. I just need to add % after the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `%` from the new value when you set state.

```js
const Example = () => {

  const initiatlState = { weight: "" };
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initiatlState);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setData({ ...data, [name]: value.replaceAll('%','') });
                                       // ^^^  sanitize the new value
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="weight" value={data.weight +"%"} 
             onChange={handleChange} placeholder="weight" />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show 50 % , the percent of input, I could suggest you show a label with that symbol.

For Example as bootstrap does
[image: Example]

And you can add it with HTML and CSS, easy input and label tag, label over the input.

Comment: I don't want that I want to add % after 50